# How to set Ethereum protocol in the genesis block file for a private Ethereum network?

Tags: private-blockchain, genesis, protocol, eip

Suppose there are some EIPs (EIPx, EIPy, EIPz) and EIPz is the latest protocol. For configuration the genesis block file in a private Ethereum network, if I set EIPz as the default protocol does that mean the network works by EIPx and EIPy too?